# Embedded C - Too many arguments to function (pointer)

Tags: c, gcc, embedded

I am trying to invoke the following macro in my .cpp file:

```
#define IAP_ROM_LOCATION                0x1FFF1FF1UL
#define IAP_EXECUTE_CMD(a, b)           ((void (*)())(IAP_ROM_LOCATION))(a, b)
```

However, when I call said function like so:

```
IAP_EXECUTE_CMD(0, 0);
```

I get an error saying too many arguments specified? How is this? I would appreciate any pointers.

Development environment is GCC for Cortex-M3.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For readability, define a signature for the function to be called:

```
typedef void signature_t(int, int);
```

Then you can cast your ROM location

```
#define IAP_EXECUTE_CMD(a, b)  ((signature_t*)IAP_ROM_LOCATION) ((a),(b))
```

and with a recent GCC (current version of GCC is **4.6**) I would make that an inline function

```
static inline void iap_execute_cmd(int a, int b) {
    ((signature_t*)IAP_ROM_LOCATION) ((a),(b));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(void (*)())(IAP_ROM_LOCATION)
```

This part casts `IAP_ROM_LOCATION` to a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing (`void (*)()`). Hence you get an error when you want to pass any arguments to that function.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with macros only:

```
#define IAP_ROM_LOCATION        0x1FFF1FF1UL
#define IAP_FUNC_SIGNATURE      void (*)(int, int)
#define IAP_EXECUTE_CMD(a, b)   ((IAP_FUNC_SIGNATURE)(IAP_ROM_LOCATION))((a), (b))
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, my C is rather rusty, but it seems to me that your IAP_EXECUTE_CMD() macro is casting the unsigned long address as a pointer to a function which returns void and accepts zero arguments. Therefore, any arguments passed to the function call would be too many.