# Passing function pointer to a function + function arguments

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have a function which I would like to pass to another function as an argument (let's call it funX). Here's funX prototype:

```
void funX(const unsigned char *, unsigned char *, size_t, const somestruct *, unsigned char *, const int);
```

and my function (lets call it funY) which calls funX:

```
unsigned char * funY(unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out, size_t len, unsigned char *i, void *k, int ed, void (*f)(unsigned char *, unsigned char *, size_t, const void *, unsigned char *, const int))
{
    f(in, out, len, k, i, ed);
}
```

But I have some warnings while compiling:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:70:5: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘funY’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
test.c:11:17: note: expected ‘void (*)(unsigned char *, unsigned char *, size_t,  const void *, unsigned char *, const int)’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(const unsigned char *, unsigned char *, size_t,  const struct somestruct *, unsigned char *, const int)’
```

Comment: Use typedef for signatures as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9143434/841108). This makes declaring a function parameter easier.

Comment: the error message seems pretty clear, the function pointer type does not correspond to the function you want to pass.

Comment: The function pointer parameter in `funY` declaration is not the same type as the type of `funX`. Just the first difference: the first arg to `funX` is a `const unsigned char *` whereas the first arg of the function pointer is a `unsigned char *`.

Answer (score 3):

See the warning and compare the prototypes

**Expected:-**

```
void (*)(unsigned char *,       unsigned char *, size_t,  const void *,              unsigned char *, const int)
```

**Provided :-**

```
void (*)(const unsigned char *, unsigned char *, size_t,  const struct somestruct *, unsigned char *, const int)
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the **entire** error message?

You have some `const`- and other type mismatches (e. g. a pointer-to-`struct` instead of `void *`, etc.) in the signature of the two functions. Function types are compatible only if their signatures match exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Your signatures seem to be different. See below.

```
void funX(const unsigned char *, unsigned char *, size_t, --> const somestruct * <--, unsigned char *, const int);

void (*f)(unsigned char *, unsigned char *, size_t, --> const void * <--, unsigned char *, const int)
```