# How to correctly assign a pointer returned by dlsym into a variable of function pointer type?

Tags: c, pointers, dlopen, dlsym

I am trying to use `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` in my code and compile it with `gcc`.

Here is the first file.

```
/* main.c */

#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
    void *handle = dlopen("./foo.so", RTLD_NOW);

    if (handle) {
        void (*func)() = dlsym(handle, "func");
        func();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the second file.

```
/* foo.c */

#include <stdio.h>

void func()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

Here is how I compile and run the code.

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -shared -fPIC -o foo.so foo.c
$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -ldl -o main main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:10:26: warning: ISO C forbids initialization between function pointer and ‘void *’ [-Wpedantic]
         void (*func)() = dlsym(handle, "func");
                          ^
$ ./main
hello, world
```

How can I get rid of the warning?

Type casting doesn't help. If I try to type cast the return value of `dlsym()` into a function pointer, I get this warning instead.

```
main.c:10:26: warning: ISO C forbids conversion of object pointer to function pointer type [-Wpedantic]
         void (*func)() = (void (*)()) dlsym(handle, "func");
                          ^
```

What would convince the compiler that this code is fine?

Comment: Don't use -pedantic warning option.

Comment: @2501 I am using the `-pedantic` option to ensure that my code is adhering strictly to the standard. Since I don't want to get rid of `-pedantic`, my question is, how can I assign the pointer returned by `dlsym()` to a function pointer variable such that it also strictly adheres to the standard? Surely, there must be a way to do it because my intention is a valid intention allowed by the dynamic linking loader.

Comment: I agree with @2501. I spent a night discussing on the legality of the assignment between a `void *` and a function pointer. But the standard subtly makes a difference between a function pointer and an object pointer (and a `void *` is such). So **formally the warning cannot be removed because the assignment is not standard compliant, but because in 99.999999999999999....999% of cases it is allowed by the Annex J, IT IS OK!**. (Sorry for the shout ;-) ).

Comment: @Frankie_C However, if I remove the `-pedantic` option I might lose other helpful pedantic warnings that might be pointing out genuine problems in my code. Why is removing the `-pedantic` option good advice?

Comment: The warning is about ISO C, but `dlsym()` is POSIX. If you're on a POSIX-compliant system, you *can* convert from `void*` to a function-pointer.

Comment: You can leave on the `-pedantic`, but just switch off the specific warning. `#pragma GCC diagnostic` should do the job. In other compilers it is `#pragma warning(disable: <warn number>)`

Comment: There have been reports of platforms where data pointers (and `void *`) are 32-bit, but function pointers even 128 bits wide. However AFAIK POSIX requires that a function pointer can also be represented as `void *`.

Comment: And dynamic linking, or even "libraries" are not within the scope of C standard.

Comment: Don't forget microcontrollers where code and data have different *address spaces*!  Casting a function pointer to `void*` and then `memcpy` from it will not read the code bytes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to be pedantically correct, don't try to resolve the address of a function. Instead, export some kind of structure from the dynamic library:

#### In the library

```
struct export_vtable {
   void (*helloworld)(void);
};
struct export_vtable exports = { func };
```

#### In the caller

```
struct export_vtable {
   void (*helloworld)(void);
};

int main() {
   struct export_vtable* imports;
   void *handle = dlopen("./foo.so", RTLD_NOW);

   if (handle) {
        imports = dlsym(handle, "exports");
        if (imports) imports->helloworld();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This technique is actually quite common, not for portability -- POSIX guarantees that function pointers can be converted to and from void* -- but because it allows more flexibility.

Answer (score 13):

This made my code sufficiently pedantic:

```
*(void**)(&func_ptr) = dlsym(handle, "function_name");
```

(I found it here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html)

Comment: I don't know why nobody's upvoted this before. It worked for and is much simpler than the other suggestions.

Comment: It violates both "pointer to data vs to function" rule as well as strict aliasing rules because `func_ptr` is modified via an incompatible type.

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is that a pointer to object is subtly separated from a function pointer. In **ISO/IEC 9899:201x** paper **§6.3.2.3 Pointers** it's stated:

> 1. A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
>    object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a
>    pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to
>    the original pointer.

.

> 8. A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to
>    a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
>    equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to
>    call a function whose type is not compatible with the pointed-to
>    type, the behavior is undefined.

So a function pointer is different from object pointers, and consequently the assignment of a `void *` to a function pointer is always **non strictly compliant**.

Anyway, as I said in comments, in 99.9999....9999% of cases it is permitted thanks to the **ANNEX J - Portability issues, §J.5.7 Function pointer casts** of the previously mentioned paper that states:

> 1. A pointer to an object or to void may be cast to a pointer to a
>    function, allowing data to be invoked as a function (6.5.4).
> 2. A pointer to a function may be cast to a pointer to an object or to
>    void, allowing a function to be inspected or modified (for example,
>    by a debugger) (6.5.4).

Now on the practical side a technique that avoid the splitting of code in more files is to use pragmas to suppress pedantic warnings for a small piece of code.
The more brutal form can be:

```
/* main.c */

#include <dlfcn.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic push    //Save actual diagnostics state
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-pedantic"    //Disable pedantic
int main()
{
    void *handle = dlopen("./foo.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (handle) {
        void (*func)() = dlsym(handle, "func");
        func();
    }
    return 0;
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop    //Restore diagnostics state
```

A more sophisticated way could be actuated isolating the offending code in a small function, then forcing its inlining. It's more a makeup than effective solution, but will suppress the unwanted diagnostic:

```
/* main.c */

#include <dlfcn.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic push    //Save actual diagnostics state
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-pedantic"    //Disable pedantic
void (*)() __attribute__((always_inline)) Assigndlsym(void *handle, char *func)
{
    return dlsym(handle, func);  //The non compliant assignment is done here
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop    //Restore diagnostics state

int main()
{
    void *handle = dlopen("./foo.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (handle) {
        void (*func)() = Assigndlsym(handle, "func"); //Now the assignment is compliant
        func();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should that be: `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-pedantic"    //Disable pedantic` ? (without the -w)?

Comment: #pragma GCC diagnostic push and pop not supported prior to gcc 4.6

Comment: The line `void (*func)() = dlsym(handle, "func");` gives me an error `Cannot initialize a variable of type 'void (*)()' with an rvalue of type 'void *'`.

Comment: @MichaelLitvin Try casting type: `void (*func)() = (void(*)())dlsym(handle, "func");`, if it still don't work and compiler refuses to assign the function pointer you're in the 0.000000....0001% of such uncompliant cases where the annex J can't apply...

Answer (score 3):

To keep the `-pedantic` option for your code while having parts of code that are not strictly conforming, separate that code into a separate file with custom warning options.

So, make a function that wraps the `dlsym` function and returns a function pointer. Put it in a separate file and compile that file without `-pedantic`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `union`, like this:

```
union {
    void *ptr;
    void (*init_google_logging) (char* argv0);
} orig_func;

orig_func.ptr = dlsym (RTLD_NEXT, "_ZN6google17InitGoogleLoggingEPKc");

orig_func.init_google_logging (argv0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX Standard [explicitly states](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html) that you can “run” an address passed as a pointer to object (emphasis mine):

> Note that conversion from a `void *` pointer to a function pointer as in:
>
> ```c
> fptr = (int (*)(int))dlsym(handle, "my_function");
> ```
>
> is not defined by the ISO C standard. **This standard requires this conversion to work correctly on conforming implementations.**

To do that you need to “animate” the object pointer first.

```c
#define ANIMATED_POINTER(FUNC_TYPE, OBJECT_POINTER) \
    (*((FUNC_TYPE *)(&(OBJECT_POINTER))))
```

You can then then invoke the object variable directly,

```c
#include <dlfcn.h>

#define ANIMATED_POINTER(FUNC_TYPE, OBJECT_POINTER) \
    (*((FUNC_TYPE *)(&(OBJECT_POINTER))))


typedef void (* MyFuncType) ();


int main () {

    void * handle = dlopen("./foo.so", RTLD_NOW);

    if (handle) {

        void * func_obj_ptr = dlsym(handle, "func");
        ANIMATED_POINTER(MyFuncType, func_obj_ptr)();

    }

    return 0;

}
```

or you can convert it into another variable of appropriate function type.

```c
#include <dlfcn.h>

#define ANIMATED_POINTER(FUNC_TYPE, OBJECT_POINTER) \
    (*((FUNC_TYPE *)(&(OBJECT_POINTER))))


typedef void (* MyFuncType) ();


int main () {

    void * handle = dlopen("./foo.so", RTLD_NOW);

    if (handle) {

        void * func_obj_ptr = dlsym(handle, "func");
        MyFuncType func = ANIMATED_POINTER(MyFuncType, func_obj_ptr);
        func();

    }

    return 0;

}
```

**Addition**

Although the conversion from an object pointer to a function pointer can be problematic, in every standard C allows to convert different types of function pointers between them. You can exploit this permission and use `void (*) (void)` as a fixed destination type for your macro.

```c
#define UNTYPED_ANIMATED_POINTER(OBJECT_POINTER) \
    (*((void (**) (void))(&(OBJECT_POINTER))))
```

Hence, imagining an `addition.c` library containing only,

```c
int add_numbers (int first, int second) {
    return first + second;
}
```

below are four variations of the same code.

**#1**

```c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define UNTYPED_ANIMATED_POINTER(OBJECT_POINTER) \
    (*((void (**) (void))(&(OBJECT_POINTER))))


int main () {

    void * handle = dlopen("./addition.so", RTLD_NOW);

    if (handle) {

        int (* add_numbers) (int, int);
        void * func_obj_ptr = dlsym(handle, "add_numbers");

        add_numbers = (int (*) (int, int)) UNTYPED_ANIMATED_POINTER(func_obj_ptr);
        int result = add_numbers(19, 23);
        printf("The result is: %d\n", result);  // "The result is: 42"

    }

    return 0;

}
```

**#2**

```c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define UNTYPED_ANIMATED_POINTER(OBJECT_POINTER) \
    (*((void (**) (void))(&(OBJECT_POINTER))))


int main () {

    void * handle = dlopen("./addition.so", RTLD_NOW);

    if (handle) {

        void * func_obj_ptr = dlsym(handle, "add_numbers");

        int result = ((int (*) (int, int)) UNTYPED_ANIMATED_POINTER(func_obj_ptr))(19, 23);
        printf("The result is: %d\n", result);  // "The result is: 42"

    }

    return 0;

}
```

**#3**

```c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define UNTYPED_ANIMATED_POINTER(OBJECT_POINTER) \
    (*((void (**) (void))(&(OBJECT_POINTER))))

typedef int (* AdditionFunc) (int, int);


int main () {

    void * handle = dlopen("./addition.so", RTLD_NOW);

    if (handle) {

        void * func_obj_ptr = dlsym(handle, "add_numbers");

        AdditionFunc add_numbers = (AdditionFunc) UNTYPED_ANIMATED_POINTER(func_obj_ptr);
        int result = add_numbers(19, 23);
        printf("The result is: %d\n", result);  // "The result is: 42"

    }

    return 0;

}
```

**#4**

```c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define UNTYPED_ANIMATED_POINTER(OBJECT_POINTER) \
    (*((void (**) (void))(&(OBJECT_POINTER))))

typedef int (* AdditionFunc) (int, int);


int main () {

    void * handle = dlopen("./addition.so", RTLD_NOW);

    if (handle) {

        void * func_obj_ptr = dlsym(handle, "add_numbers");

        int result = ((AdditionFunc) UNTYPED_ANIMATED_POINTER(func_obj_ptr))(19, 23);
        printf("The result is: %d\n", result);  // "The result is: 42"

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score -3):

The compiler only "tries to help", so you have to use two typecasts:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void (*func)() = (void (*)())(intptr_t)dlsym(handle, "func");
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast states that "here are no conversions between pointers to functions and integers". for more details see references to standard below.

Comment: The _existence_ of `dlsym` proves that on the system in question (most likely, but not necessarily POSIX) you can (and have to) convert from data-pointer to code-pointer.