# dlsym() workaround return type

Tags: c++, dlsym

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) of `dlsym()` lists

```
   *(void **) (&cosine) = dlsym(handle, "cos");
```

as a workaround for casting the return value of `dlsym()`.

What's the meaning of `*(void **) (&cosine)` here? I understand `cosine` is a function pointer defined previously, but I'm not sure why an ampersand `&` is needed before the name (an error without `&`). Moreover, I don't figure out why the pointer of `void *` (`void **`) is again used with `*`.

Comment: This assumes an earlier declaration of `double (*cosine)(double);` or similar.

Comment: Very common question. This 'solution' works perfectly, if data-pointers and code-pointers are of the same size. Otherwise it fails spectacularly.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond You are right in general, but `dlsym` specifically comes from POSIX, which mandates that this works in a conforming implementation. In other words, POSIX only permits platforms with a flat memory model, where all pointers are the same.

Comment: @ephemient I think I know a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36388869/4844822

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy No. Read the example and rationale on [POSIX.1-2001](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html).

Comment: @ephemient I fail to see anything in the linked text regading intptr_t; the statement I feel most relevant is this: "Implementations supporting the XSI extension, however, do require that an object of type void * can hold a pointer to a function." If we assume that `intptr_t` can hold a `void *` we can say that my solution works in every situation where sizeof (intptr_t) >= sizeof (void *) >= sizeof (void (*)()); whilst the suggested solution works if and only if  sizeof (void *) == sizeof (void (*)())

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy Just because they're the same size doesn't mean you can cast between them. By the C standard, it is completely legal for the compiler to treat a data or function pointer cast to a function pointer of a different type as an invalid value (because it's undefined behavior).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's unwrap it a bit at a time:

```
&cosine
```

This takes a pointer to the variable `cosine`, so this will be a pointer to a function pointer.

```
(void **) &cosine
```

We cast the pointer-to-function-pointer to pointer-to-pointer-to-void.

```
* (void **) &cosine
```

We dereference the casted pointer, assigning the result of `dlsym()` into it.

Effectively, what's happening is a side-step of the issue.  Instead of casting the result of `dlsym()` into the correct type of function pointer, we pretend that `cosine` is a `void *` (through a level of indirection) and assign to it.

Comment: Right. C doesn't define casting between data pointers and function pointers. POSIX, which defines `void *dlsym(const char *, int)`, does imply that it is possible to represent a function pointer in a `void *` (which is a guarantee not made in standard C), but that doesn't get around the fact that casting a `void *` to a function pointer is not well-defined. Here, `&cosine` is a data pointer (to a function pointer), and casting a data pointer through `void *` and back is allowed, so this keeps us on safe ground.

Comment: @ephemient, are you sure that it solves the problem? `void*` and `double (*)(double)` don't seem to be compatible types, so that would run afoul of strict aliasing rules instead of relying on function pointers being convertible to `void*`. Violating strict aliasing causes UB, but the compiler has a real chance to warn/error out on an incorrect explicit conversion. It seems to me that you'd be better off casting and statically checking if the compiler lets you do it rather than possibly break at runtime due to UB.

Comment: @zneak That's the recommendation in the [POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html), and in general, C allows pointer aliasing through `void *` and `char *`. This is one of the areas where POSIX has requirements that standard C does not otherwise have.

Comment: @ephemient, my understanding is that the pointer aliasing allowance is one way: `char*` to `something*`, then modifying `*something` and reading back through `*char` is legal, but `something*` to `char*`, then modifying `*char` and then read back `*something` is not.

Comment: The POSIX documentation does say that a conforming implementation would have to emit a warning for a direct cast from `void*` to a function pointer, but it seems to me that as far as pedantic conformance goes, if I'm not misinterpreting strict aliasing, neither is great but their workaround is arguably worse.

Comment: @zneak A value may be read or written through a pointer of the associated type or a character type. This permits implementations of `memcpy` in C.

Comment: @ephemient, that's convincing; but a `void*` (as `memcpy` uses) and a `void**` (as this trick uses) are different.

Comment: @zneak An implementation of `memcpy` can legally cast `void *` to `char *` internally to copy.

Comment: @ephemient, yes, and the question is not what `memcpy` does. I'm willing to believe that the *contents* of a `void*` ("`*voidptr`", resulting type `void` if you could write that) can legally alias with anything; can the contents of a `void**` ("`*voidptrptr`, resulting type `void*`) do too?

Comment: @zneak By the C standard, no, but it is required to work on all POSIX-compliant systems. See https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/interps/1003.1-2001/1003.1-2001-03.html

Comment: @ephemient, I see that, and it confirms that casting the result pointer, or casting the pointer to the output variable, are both required to work with POSIX. That seems to mean, however, that neither is more portable than the other. Going back to my previous comment, in terms of either getting a program that works or advance notice that it won't, it seems safer to me  to cast the return value. Unless I'm missing something else, I personally wouldn't advise anyone to use the suggested workaround on the grounds of portability.