# dlopen for different libraries? C

Tags: c, libraries, dlopen, dlsym

Hi I am working on a program that works like this:

`./Filters File [filters...]`

The filters can be a lot of .so libraries that I want to create myself and aply them to the File. But all of the libraries have the same function `process(a1,a2,a3)`, it's just that each of them do something different.

I'm trying to use it like this:

```
/*Open the library*/
if (!(descriptor_lib=dlopen(dir_filter, RTLD_LAZY))) {
    fprintf(stderr, MYNAME": %s\n", dlerror());
    return(1);
}

/*We find the function we want to use*/
if (!(fn=dlsym(descriptor_bib, "process"))) {
    fprintf(stderr, MYNAME": %s\n", dlerror());
    return(1);
}

/*And then I try to use the function*/
printf("Number of chars readed: %d", fn(a1, a2, a3));
```

But I get this error when I try to compile: `error: too many arguments to function ‘fn’`

`dir_filter` is the direction of the library, but its a variable, cause I make a loop to read all the filters, copy in dir_filter the actual one, and then use the code above.

And I think that if I specify the `dir_filter` with the name of the library, it will work, but I can't do that cause I need to make it work for different filters (different libraries), it will not be always the same. Now i only have 3 libraries but if in a future i wat to expand it i don't want to extend the code everytime I add a new library.

So what I'm doing wrong, or it's imposible to work with dlopen with a variable?

EDIT: The function process is something like this:

```
int process(char*buff_in, char*buff_out, int tam)
```

EDIT2: With `typedef` i could fix the function pointer, that was the problem. Thanks for the replies and sorry for my english.

Comment: Show the declaration of `fn` and of all the types related to it. So **edit your question to improve it**. You might want to use a `typedef` for its signature, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9143434/841108)

Comment: The issue isn't the type of the process functions but the type of the function pointer which you still don't show after the update.

Comment: How would the compiler know what types to pass to `fn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `process` function is declared (in your plugin code) as

```
int process(int, int, int);
```

Then, you'll better [define](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9143434/841108) a `typedef` for its signature (within the main program doing the `dlsym`):

```
typedef int process_sig_t (int, int, int);
```

And you'll use that to declare the function pointer (there are some "direct" ways to declare in C a function [pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer) without using a `typedef` for its signature, but I find them less readable).

```
process_sig_t *fnptr = NULL;
```

The compiler would then know the signature of the function referenced by that pointer.

<sup>(the initialization of `fnptr` to `NULL` could be omitted; it makes the code more readable and less error prone, since with a more reproducible behavior)</sup>

which you would fill using `dlsym` e.g.

```
if (!(fnptr=dlsym(descriptor_bib, "process"))) {
  fprintf(stderr, MYNAME": %s\n", dlerror());
  return(1);
}
```

The use it

```
printf("Number of chars read: %d\n", (*fnptr) (a1, a2, a3));
```

BTW, function pointers could be called directly:

```
// less readable code, we don't know that fnptr is a function pointer
printf("Number of chars read: %d\n", fnptr (a1, a2, a3));
```

<sup>(it is better to end most `printf` format strings with `\n`; otherwise call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) since `stdout` is often line-buffered)</sup>

BTW, your question is mostly about understanding function pointers (it would be relevant if the function pointer was obtained thru something else than `dlsym`, e.g. using some [JIT compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library like [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/)).

Comment: Hey, Thanks so much for that specific. I could fix the issue. By the way, i update the format of the function `process` in the main post.