# How to pass a void function(void) in to another function as parameter in c

Tags: c, parameters, function-call, function-declaration

[enter image description here][1]I have a function `void readline()` which output a string, and I want to pass it into another function as a parameter, how can I do that,

Thanks for any help.

```
int scorecount(argc1, argv1, void readline());
void readline();


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    scorecount(argc,argv);
}


int scorecount(argc1, argv1, void readline()){

    output a int
    and I want to use the string from readline function somewhere in
    scorecount

}


void readline(){

    output a string

}
```

Comment: You need to show more code, your question is unclear as it stands here. Or you may need to read your C text book.

Comment: you are saying that readline will give u output string and you want to pass it into another function the that readline function return type should be "string"

Comment: Maybe you want [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) but it does not return a `void`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9143434/841108

Comment: Why have you linked to the actual code, and typed in some distant approximation of that code? Please read about, and then provide, a [MCVE] in the text of your question.

Answer (score 5):

You can declare the parameter as the function declaration using any name of the parameter. For example

```
void another_function( void readline( void ) );
```

And the function `another_function` can be called like

```
another_function( readline );
```

The compiler adjusts the function declaration to pointer to the function. So the above declaration is equivalent to

```
void another_function( void ( *readline )( void ) );
```

EDIT: After you updated your code then the function should be declared like

```
int scorecount( int argc, char * argv[], void readline( void ) );
void readline( void );
```

and called like

```
scorecount( argc, argv, readline );
```

Comment: I'm very new to Stack overflow, how can I put my code here so you guys can see it?

Comment: @HuYunfei Is my answer unclear or do you have one more problem?

Comment: I want to pass readline func into a function which has already passed argc and argv in the parameter, and I applied your solution, error appears

Comment: @HuYunfei Update your question.

Comment: @HuYunfei Do not give a reference to an image. Type the code in your question.

Comment: please see the screen shot of my code, thank you

Comment: @HuYunfei Type the code an the error message in the question instead of providing a reference.

Comment: @HuYunfei Reread my answer. I showed how the function should be called.

Comment: I have put a piece of code here, please see it