# Difficulty in understanding function-pointers in c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am reading The C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup. It somewhere uses using keyword to make function-pointer datatypes P1 and P2 like this:

```
using P1 = int(∗)(int∗);

using P2 = void(∗)(void);
```

But then it uses using keyword to make another function-pointer datatype:

```
using CFT = int(const void∗, const void∗);             -(1)
```

then it uses CFT to declare a function-pointer and passes it in some ssort function:

```
void ssort(void∗ base, siz e_t n, size_t sz, CFT cmp);
```

My question is if it is making a function-pointer datatype using "using"  then shouldn't line-(1) be:

```
using CFT=int(*)(const void*, const void*);
```

rather than what it actually is?

Comment: which edition? Did you check the errata if they mention it there?

Comment: 4th edition.didn't check, would do so.

Comment: @Default: Where is the errata in the book?

Comment: @Birbal: It's not in the book. If they knew the mistakes when they published the book, they wouldn't have made them. Google _"the c++ programming language 4th edition errata"_.

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9143434/841108) answer. It might be helpful

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: It doesn't seem to add anything relevant, except for switching from the modern `using` to the antiquated `typedef`.

Comment: In that case, using `typedef` makes a more uniform syntax (same look as a function declaration), which might be more readable

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The purpose of `using` is to be far more readable and personally I think it succeeds. C declarator syntax is notoriously esoteric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C and C++, the `(*)` is optional here.

Yes, this is confusing. It's an oddity regarding function pointer types.

It would have been better had the author stuck to *one* of the two possible syntaxen.

Comment: Looking for a standard quote but can't actually find one. I think the types are different but end up being used the same.

Comment: they are not the same. It seems like in the context of function parameters are the same. https://godbolt.org/g/EhVV5Z

Comment: So what I just said then :)

Comment: yeah. It is very confusing. `void call(F f)` and `void call2(F* f)` have the same signature if `F` is a function type.

Comment: It's maddening - I do try to avoid naked function pointers, probably at the expense of a bit of runtime overhead with `std::function` ahem :D

Comment: It is indeed a distinct and incomplete [function type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#def:function_type). And it has its uses and oddities. I personally like that one may use the original `CFT` to make pointer semantics explicit, i.e. `CFT*`. Not to mention being able to use it with `std::function`, as you already mentioned.