# What does this pointer notation mean?

Tags: c

```
#define START ((void (**)(int)) 0x0fff)

*START = &fun_foo();
```

I haven't seen this before. What is happening here? Is void (**)(int) a function pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void (**)(int)` is a pointer to a pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns nothing.

So `START` is apointer to a function pointer, and `*START` is the actual function pointer which is set to point to `fun_foo`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `START` is a pointer (located at the fixed address `0x0fff`) to a function pointer.

But as I suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8310429/841108), for readability reasons, you may want to use a `typedef` for the signature of that pointed function.