# change the C function contents at run-time

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, writable

I have a use-case in which the function contents are to be selected conditionally. And that function pointer is passed to other module for later invocation.

```
void encode_function(int flag)
{
 if (flag == 1)
  encode1();
 if (flag == 2)
  encode2();

  encode_defaults();
}
```

Once the encode_function() is populated, I will pass it to other module, where it will be invoked.
I am trying to achieve it in C language, but no success so far. I tried to look at [dyncall](http://dyncall.org/) library but it supports only dynamic parameter changes.

I am looking for something which allows me to change the function contents at run-time.

Some existing question [Is there a way to modify the code of a function in a Linux C program at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947388/is-there-a-way-to-modify-the-code-of-a-function-in-a-linux-c-program-at-runtime)

Comment: `change the function contents at run-time` why don't have separate functions and use function pointer array to select the function to be called at runtime?

Comment: Generate code and compile it as a DLL/Shared library and load the dll at runtime?

Comment: Do you really need to change the function contents at run time?  Or, will selecting from a few known functions suffice?

Comment: If speed is not that much of a concern, you can also integrate V8 or LUA etc. into your application and simply execute new versions of the scripts.

Comment: There are ways to do it in other languages that has functional programming support. The best way I can think of to do it in C is to wrap the parameter and function pointer together in a struct and send them together.

Comment: You could invent your own Domain specifiic mini language and write a small interpreter for it. Then you could simply give the function a new "dsl program" to interpret. This is not necessarily slow or much work. With like 500 lines you already are in the game.

Comment: how do you know which content you are changing the function to? if everything can be determined in compile time, why not a switch case?

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh Due to large no of conditions, using a function pointer array is not feasible.

Comment: @user2225104 I am trying to change unix kernel code for performance gains (should have mentioned earlier).

Comment: Then write and load new kernel modules.

Comment: @user3528438 hmm let me try if this is feasible, can you point me to some examples.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf <<-- Kernel module programming guide (PDF)

Comment: I am trying to club multiple file system operation and send it over to network server. For every set of operations if I try to load/unload a module, it is a bad design.

Comment: So, you want to partially apply a function, optimize that, and then pass a pointer to it?

Comment: I did this by adding all the function pointers to a struct list, pass the list to a a generic function which can be invoked later. It served my purpose. Thanks @user3528438 for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You are basically looking for the ability to treat code as data, which is a feature rarely available in compiled imperative static languages like c. The capability of modifying functions at run time is generally categorized as high order functions (you're basically trying to return a function as data somewhere in the code).

If the problem can be solved by several static functions, you can pass in function pointers to different implementations, otherwise I think c does not have the ability to really treat code as data and modify them on the fly.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535631/higher-order-functions-in-c) makes attempt to implement high order function in c, but going this far might not be what you want.

Comment: Hmm..  looks like there is no development being done to C language.

Comment: @BharatSingh languages may look like car series to you in the manner of constant remodeling and adding new features every a couple of years. but that really is not the case. The purpose of c is to carry out effective manipulation with in a chunk of memory, while other languages has other purpose, such as fast oo modeling on business logic. You might need a course on compiling theory to get a solid grasp on this topic.